# Using rowDiffs() to calculate difference in values in matrix

Tags: r

I'm using the `rowDiffs` command (from the `matrixStats` package) to calculate the step by step difference in 116 rows in a matrix.

I get the following error:

```
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I could take the diff() separately for each row and it would work.

Any ideas?

Here's the data:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/data.csv

Code:

```
a = rowDiffs(data)
```

Comment: str(data) show it's a data.frame. As Romain suggested, rowDiffs(as.matrix(data)) works well on your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

`rowDiffs` works on matrices. This works for me:

```
rowDiffs( as.matrix(data) )
```